# How to link an ESP 8266 to a Raspberry Pi LAMP Web server in order to make POST requests?

Tags: request, raspberry-pi, webserver, client, esp8266

I am currently using the `AT` command and am getting an error. The specific command I am using:

```
AT+CISTART="TCP","10.0.0.21",80
```

`10.0.0.21` is my PI's IP address, but I keep getting "error  closed" in response. I am sure that both the esp8266 and my Raspberry PI are connected to my wifi.

Comment: a `P` is missing in the command ? It should be `AT+CIPSTART`. Did you check that both are on the same network using `AT+CIPSTA?` ?